# "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" and stopping zero errors

Tags: python, arrays, vector

I'm using this code as part of a project to simulate orbits of 3 bodies. I am using the Euler method in this part but i am getting some errors that i am not sure how to get rid of.

```
import vpython as v
from numpy import arange, linspace, array
import numpy as np

np.seterr(divide='ignore')
Earth = array([-1.47E+11, 0, 0, -30290])
Mars = array([-2.07E+11, 0, 0, -26500])

def derivatives(Body1, Body2, t):
    Mass_earth = 5.97E+24
    Mass_mars = 6.42E+23
    Mass_sun = 1.99E+30
    Abs_Radius_earth = 1.47E+11
    Abs_Radius_mars = 2.07E+11
    Radius_earth = array([Body1[0], Body1[1]])
    Radius_mars = array([Body2[0], Body2[1]])
    ve = 1
    vm = 1
    G = 6.67408E-11
    dvedt = (G*Mass_sun*Radius_earth)/(np.abs(Abs_Radius_earth))**3 +       np.divide((G*Mass_mars*(Radius_mars-Radius_earth)), (np.abs(Radius_mars-Radius_earth))**3)
    dvmdt = (G*Mass_sun*Radius_mars)/(np.abs(Abs_Radius_mars))**3 + np.divide((G*ME*(Radius_earth-Radius_mars)), (np.abs(Radius_earth-Radius_mars))**3)
    dvedt = v.vector(float(dvedt[0]), float(dvedt[1]), 0)
    return(ve, vm, dvedt, dvmdt)

Evol = array([Earth[2], Earth[3]])
Epol = array([Earth[0], Earth[1]])
Mvol = array([Mars[2], Mars[3]])
Mpol = array([Mars[0], Mars[1]])
E = array([Epol, Evol])
M = array([Mpol, Mvol])

for t in arange(1, 11, 1):
    Evol += (t * derivatives(E, M, 1)[2])
    E = array([Epol, Evol])
    print(E, M)
```

Here is the error message:

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:20: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:21: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-ef24509c2299> in <module>()
     31 
     32 for t in arange(1, 11, 1):
---> 33     Evol += (t * derivatives(E, M, 1)[2])
     34     E = array([Epol, Evol])
     35     print(E, M)

<ipython-input-25-ef24509c2299> in derivatives(Body1, Body2, t)
     20     dvedt = (G*Mass_sun*Radius_earth)/(np.abs(Abs_Radius_earth))**3 + np.divide((G*Mass_mars*(Radius_mars-Radius_earth)), (np.abs(Radius_mars-Radius_earth))**3)
     21     dvmdt = (G*Mass_sun*Radius_mars)/(np.abs(Abs_Radius_mars))**3 + np.divide((G*ME*(Radius_earth-Radius_mars)), (np.abs(Radius_earth-Radius_mars))**3)
---> 22     dvedt = v.vector(float(dvedt[0]), float(dvedt[1]), 0)
     23     return(ve, vm, dvedt, dvmdt)
     24 

TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

This is probably a simple fix but I just cant seem to get it to work. I'm mainly focusing on all the earth parts, if i can get that working i will apply it to the other planets (mars).
Any help will be super helpful.

Comment: 1.  What is the type of the values in the failing expression?  In particular, what is `derivatives(E, M, 1)[2]`.  2.  I would track down what those RunTimeWarnings are about - they may actually be the cause of your problem.  3. (Astronomy, not programming) I notice you are modelling the interaction of mars and earth - I am pretty sure that Jupiter is a much more significant influence on both of them.

Comment: I suggest you work it through by writing a comment at the end of each line, stating the shape of each and every array as it is defined.   The problem is that `dvedt[0]` and `dvedt[1]` are not scalars (and your code clearly expects them to be scalars since it passes them as arguments to `float()`  ).  It follows that you are implicitly expecting `dvedt` to be one-dimensional, when in fact it is two- or more-dimensional.   Working through with comments, from the beginning, will show you the source of this error. Martin is right that this error may stem from the failed divisions in lines 20 & 21.